# Add a close button to toggle box js

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to add a close button at the bottom of this toggle box. Can somebody help me with the script please? Thanks.

```
  <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="heading">Business Management in the Global Economy <small>(2+2 Program)</small></a>
    <div class="info-hidden info" style="height:380px;">
      <p>
        <b>Program Description:</b><br />
        Some Text.......
        <br />
        <a href="/programs/bachelors-in-business-management-in-the-global-economy.php" class="nudge">
          <b>Learn More &#9658;</b>
          <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close &#9746;</a>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </td>
```

The script looks like this - really simple.

```
// slide toggle
  $(".info").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".heading").click(function()
    {
      $(this).next(".info").slideToggle(300);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('div.info-hidden.info').slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gzyGq/2/)**.

Comment: That example works in the fiddle just fine but not in my page... I'm not sure what I have going on here... http://www.acot.edu/pages/programs-offered.php

Comment: Also - I changed the link so that I didn't have a link within a link.

Answer (score 0):

I used this....

```
// slide toggle
$(".info").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
$(".heading").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".info").slideToggle(400);
});
$(".closeToggle").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".info").slideToggle();
});
```